# has_many :through relationships explained

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to Rails and have some doubts about the kind of relationship do I need to use. Here is the case.

I have two models Offer and User, a user could belong to to many offers and offers can have many user. Also the users create the offers.

I think I have to use a has_many :through ralationship. For example I've created another model "Applicant". Applicant belongs_to user and belongs_to offer. But how is the relationship from the user and offer model? For example:

User Model

```
 has_many :offer, :through => :applicant
```

Offer Model

```
 has_many :user, :through => :applicant
```

My doubt is because I already have this two relationship

User Model

```
has_many :offers, :dependent => :destroy
```

Offer Model

```
belongs_to :user
```

After solve this, I guest I have to save the record in the applicant model from the applicanst_controller, right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have described is a [many-to-many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) relationship using a join table. You're actually pretty close but you just need to remove the `has_many :offers, :dependent => :destroy` from your user model and the `blongs_to :user` in your offer model. It should look something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :offers, :through => :applicants
end

class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :offers
end


class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :applicants
end
```

You don't have to worry about the dependent destroy part as associations are automatically removed as the corresponding objects are removed. With a many to many association it doesn't really matter how you go about building the relationship. Either of the following will work:

```
@user.offers << @offer

@offers.users << @user
```

If you don't need to store any information specific to your applicant join table (e.g., time stamps, descriptions) you might instead want to look at a [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) relationship. Check out [choosing between has_many_through and has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many) for reference.

### Edit

Heres the code for a HABTM relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :offers
end


class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Comment: Thanks Cyle, but I have antoher question...the users create the offers and I use the user has_many offers and offer belongs_to user to associate the records, so if I delete this association, this does not going to affect, when a user creates an offer??? the Applicant model is just for know what user apply to a what offer

Comment: With the first solution I recommended, if you delete the offer no users will have an association with that offer anymore and the associated user objects will remain, and vice versa. If you don't wish to store any extra information regarding applicants you might want to consider a HABTM solution instead, see my updated answer. If you want associated User objects to be deleted along with their associated Offers you can use the :autosave option along with the HABTM association as described [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many)

Comment: Well definitely I don't need to store any other information, I just need that user could still create offers and other users, could apply to any offer. So I have to change to HABTM, but after I made this change I get this error SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: offers_users: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "offers_users" ON "users"."id" = "offers_users"."user_id" WHERE "offers_users"."offer_id" = 1

Comment: Forget it, I create del model offers_users and I thinks everythings work great, let me check but know I dont know how to create the applicants. I thinks I'm doing something wrong because this table just create the relationship between users and offers but no applicants